# Validation Class - should return false or throw exception?

Tags: php

I am creating a class that validates strings. There are many reasons why the string might not pass.

Would it make more sense to throw an exception, or return false/error code? Pros/cons?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

validators should not throw exceptions, as failing a validator is not an "exceptional" event.

the rest of your code should throw exceptions if it gets bad data.

when you run a validator function you are clearly prepared to handle any problems detected with a simple test.  wrapping everything in a try/catch block and stopping all execution only to try to recover is overkill.  Just use and if statement, and be prepared to show the user some error messages.

Comment: I actually find there is an exception to this. For example, when writing a web service, in my repositories, I will assert whether or not an entity is valid. This way, I can validate, halt execution and handle the response in a very conventional way with minimal code.

Comment: @Tres that seems like a reasonable exception to me.

Comment: A validator indeed should not be expected to throw exceptions on invalid data. Out of the context of the validator; letting assertions throw exceptions allows you to "skip service layers" and catch the exception on a higher level (e.g. controller). So yes, letting assertions throw exceptions is perfectly fine, and the validator should catch these exceptions as the validator indeed shouldn't be expected to throw exceptions. Having to check assertion return values could be considered a SRP violation.

Answer (score 2):

Return `false`.
Exception is EXCEPTION, and should be thrown in exceptional cases only, when script can't continue execution.

Comment: Having an exceptional case and not being able to continue the script are two absolutely different things. When some value is asserted to be valid, then the fact that the value is not valid thereby is an exception. The validator that actually does do these assertions can simply catch these exceptions.

Comment: > the fact that the value is not valid thereby is an exception 

-
no, it's just one of two possible values returned by the validator

Comment: This is all about the responsibility per class, so let each class do what it does best. Let an assertion assert, let a validator validate. The validation outcome true|false|exception is not a possible value for the validator, the validator is a supportive service that should in any circumstance return the validation results. It is up for the callee (e.g. controller) to thereafter determine whether within the related scope that result is considered to be valid and act upon that (e.g. return http 403).

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an exception seems a bit extreme, as a string not validating isn't really an *exceptional* event as far as a string validation suite is concerned.

As such, I'd have thought that returning false would seem the most logical solution. Additionally, you could also pass back a meaningful textual error via a reference variable, if this makes sense as far as your implementation is concerned.

For example:

```
// In the class definition...
public function validateSTring($stringToValidate, &$errorString=null) {

    // If an error occurs...
    if($errorString) {
        $errorString = 'Something went wrong along the way.';
        return false;
    }     

}


// When calling...

$errorString = '';
$validationSuite->validateString($stringToValidate, $errorString);
```

Comment: The validating itself is not an exceptional event, but when the string would not be valid that is an exception to the assertion that happens on the subject. So, in these situations throwing an exception is perfectly fine. Making a specific exception class even puts you more in control over the stack depth on which you would want to catch it, for instance in a situation on a domain layer where you would want to use such an assertion without validator and catch the exception on the application layer (while there could sit an inversed dependency to the infrastructure layer in the middle).

Comment: @Rvanlaak `"when the string would not be valid that is an exception to the assertion that happens on the subject"` the validator should determine if is valid, true/false. If false (is invalid) that is not exceptional, it is a legitimate outcome from the validator "this is not valid".

Comment: Yes, as I stated as well by saying "The validating itself is not an exceptional event", meaning it's the validator's responsibility to return false/true. The whole point is that an assertion by definition asserts if some statement is true, and throws an exception otherwise. This is a clear and powerful distinction in each of the two's responsibilities. The validator solely will have to support by catching the possible exceptions the assertion trows and then indeed return false (with context) when that happens.